# Why did sailing ships so often employ Chinese cooks?

Tags: china, food, age-of-sail, labour-history

During the age of sail, it was common for Western ships to employ Chinese cooks. I don't have any numbers except that there are pages and pages of relevant results from search queries including "Chinese cook", "cocinero chino", and so on.

As of 1882, "there are many [Chinese men] in the coasting trade as cooks and stewards" (from "Chinese Sailors: America's Invisible Merchant Marine 1876-1905").

Insofar as all cultures produce professional cooks, what explains the shipboard prominence of Chinese ones? Chinese food is delicious, but surely other factors were in play as well: possibly lower wages, an ability to cook in more styles, etc.

[image: Portrait of a Chinese cook with queue]

Comment: Might your impression come from a sampling bias. As in a Chinese cook was odd enough to get a mentioned, whereas a European one did not, thereby creating the impression there were a lot of Chinese cooks when in fact there were not?

Comment: Not only ships. Chinese cuisine is popular everywhere where it is available. For example, most foreign restaurants in the US are Chinese.

Comment: Good question, [related Wikipedia page about Coolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coolie) page (I assume). Also likely related to [being Shanghaiied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghaiing) and other forms of slavery.

Comment: I'd think for most of the Age of Sail it would be rare to find a ship (merchant or warship) that had a dedicated cook. In most cases, they would be just another hand. Cooking facilities would be primative and preparing meals on the rolling deck of a ship with limited kitchen stores would be far from the experience of a professional cook.

Comment: Here is an article that mentions the frequent employment of Chinese sailors as cooks. It seems the descriminatory exclusion of Chinese from higher paid / more desirable jobs may explain their prevelance in that role. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0144039X.2010.504533

Comment: @BrianZ Interesting. I can't access it but that sounds like quite a lead.

Comment: @Alex The restaurants in the US are very diverse.  No cuisine accounts for a majority of foreign restaurants, and I'm pretty sure the honor of having a plurality belongs to Italian restaurants, not Chinese restaurants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Discrimination against the Chinese** was clearly a key factor, excluding them from higher paid and more desirable jobs aboard ship. Here is a quote from [the article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0144039X.2010.504533) "‘I Espied a Chinaman’: Chinese Sailors and the Fracturing of the Nineteenth Century Pacific Maritime Labour Force" by John T. Grider, published in the journal *Slavery & Abolition* (2010).

> White sailors did not mind when Chinese worked in domestic jobs, such
>   as cooks, stewards, cabin boys, mess boys, storekeepers, bakers,
>   porters, pantrymen, and waiters. In domestic roles Chinese did not
>   pose a threat to white concepts of labour-based masculinity, but when
>   Chinese worked in the rigging or in the engine room of steamships,
>   resentment grew. Anger towards Chinese sailors increased substantially
>   when the Pacific Mail Steamship Company replaced white and
>   black sailors with their Chinese counterparts in 1867 in order to save
>   money on wages and food stores.
>
> During the early nineteenth century, very few Chinese men shipped out
>   aboard foreign vessels as seamen. Most Chinese men who did ship out did
>   so as cooks and stewards, and they eventually became a common feature
>   on Pacific vessels by midcentury.